# SQL Query - Union Help Please

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and am having a hard time writing a query for something. Let's say I have a table ( school_info) that looks like this:

```
                      |  High School         | College 
_________________________________________________________________________
Mom_Age | pet|  sibling|  fresh | soph | jun | sen |fresh |soph |jun  |sen
__________________________________________________________________________
<40     | yes|      1  |  x?    |
```

I don't know if the table is readable but basically there are two categories (high school and college) which are divided by freshman, sophomore, junior and senior. I want to know how I'd write an SQL query to figure out how many freshman high school students have a mom under 40, a pet and 1 sibling. I'm unsure how to unionize in SQL.

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: We need to see the actual table structure, because a normal table cannot have the subdivisions you represent here unless they are flattened into column names. Post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE school_info` so we can see the true layout.

Comment: I only know how to get column by column or by rows. I can write a query for how many freshman there are, but I don't know how to write one for how many high school freshman there are with said characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would first do is get the list of students who meet all of your criteria:

```
SELECT student_id, category, year
FROM studentTable
WHERE mom_age < 40 AND sibling = 1 AND pet = 'yes';
```

Once you have that, you can group by (category, year) using the above as a subquery to get the counts you need:

```
SELECT category, year, COUNT(*) AS numStudents
FROM studentTable
WHERE mom_age < 40 AND sibling = 1 AND pet = 'yes'
GROUP BY category, year;
```

Comment: This is correct but I do not think you need the sub query. All you would need to do is, at the Count(*) and Group by to the first query and remove the Student_ID or do a Count(Distinct Student_ID)